# how to connect to wifi programmatically for Android Things 1.0.2

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-wifi, android-things

I am trying to connect to Wifi network programmatically through our app that is deployed on Android Things 1.0.2. I followed the turorial(https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/02/15/connecting-wifi-xamarin-forms/). The code for wifi setting is as follows:

```
var ssid = "linksys";
var password = "123";
var wifiManager = (WifiManager)Android.App.Application.Context
                        .GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
var formattedSsid = $"\"{ssid}\"";
var formattedPassword = $"\"{password}\"";
wifiManager.EnableNetwork(true);
var wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration
            {
                Ssid = formattedSsid,
                PreSharedKey = formattedPassword
            };
var addNetwork = wifiManager.AddNetwork(wifiConfig);
var network = wifiManager.ConfiguredNetworks
                 .FirstOrDefault(n => n.Ssid == ssid);

if (network == null)
   {
     Console.WriteLine($"Cannot connect to network: {ssid}");
     return;
   }

wifiManager.Disconnect();
var enableNetwork = wifiManager.EnableNetwork(network.NetworkId, true);
```

But I got null result when I tried to get "ConfiguredNetworks" on "WifiManager". I also tried to manually grant the two android permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

through adb command but got the "permission is not changable" error. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I'm not actually that familiar that Xamarin, so it may be hard to help, although I do have experience with adding networks. I think what you're doing is correct, as it's not different on Android Things. What commands are you running in ADB? Are you seeing any odd errors in logcat in the wifi manager?

Comment: @NickFelker The command that I used was "pm grant Droid.CribMasterValueLine android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE". The error I got was "Javalang SecurityException: Access_wifi_state permission android_permission.Change_Wifi_State is not a changeable permission type".

Comment: I believe those permissions are not considered "dangerous" and are always granted in an app as long as it's declared.